# Recover files from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss, data-corruption

I was trying to move (ctrl + X) from Ubuntu Desktop to a memory card. Moved upto 8G files but unfortunately the card reader disturbed. Got error and when I re insert the card reader I got another error. Inserted card reader in windows machine and I could see only 500MB data. I do not find the data in Ubuntu desktop as well. How to find those image files. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is basically the same question as this one: http://askubuntu.com/q/789150/271

Comment: *Some error* can usually resolved by *some action*. Can you please be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the disturbance has corrupted your card.

Install `foremost`, make sure you have enough space in your current directory (possibly make a new directory & `CD` to it), run `foremost`, go to the pub for an hour or three, and you should find all your missing files categorised by type (but without original names) when you get back.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Will try and let you know the result. If needed please help me further. :)

Comment: Since the copy process was halted before it was complete, he should attempt proper recovery on the source drive, not on the destination drive. Also, data carving should be used as a last resort, given the many disadvantages it has.

Comment: Maybe, but at least this doesn't damage the card any & is likely to work. Feel free to detail the process in a separate answer?